# Why it was not rendering events in full-calendar from WEB SERVICE?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
//My web-service method WebService1.asmx

[WebMethod]    
[ScriptMethod]    
public string GetAllEvents()    
{    
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("[{\"id\":\"36\"title\":\"Birthday party\",\"start\":\"2013-09-18\",\"end\":\"2013-09-18\",\"allDay\":false}]");
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = jss.Serialize(list.ToArray());
     return strJSON;
}

//My jQuery snippet

$("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar({

eventSources: 

[    
  {         
     url: "http://localhost:49322/WebService1.asmx/GetAllEvents",         
     type: 'POST',         
     dataType: "json",         
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
 }    
]    
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information (for example your HTML is missing) or - even better - put together a jsFiddle.

Comment: For what its worth, I recently posted some C# code on how to do this with an ASHX file: http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/fullcalendar-json-feed-httphandler-csharp/ If this is an option instead of web service, let me know and I'll post code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the wrong track.

- Don't form your json strings manually using string operations (As in your case, it is an invalid json).
- Don't return string from your web method, return the real object

It should be something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Event> GetAllEvents()
{
    List<Event> events = .......
    ..fill the list....
    return evetns;
}



public class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: public class Events

{
   
    public string start;

    public string title;

}

public List<Events> GetAllEvents()

{

   List<Events> events = new List<Events>();

   events.Add(new Events() {title="Birthday",start="2013-09-23"});

   return events;

}


//After this how to convert it to JSON object and where?

Comment: @ChaitanyaMoganti No need to serialize your object to json manually. It will be done automatically, see the attribute(`[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`)

Comment: $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar({

eventSources: 

[    
  {         
     url: "http://localhost:49322/WebService1.asmx/GetAllEvents",         
     type: 'POST',         
     dataType: "json",         
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
 }    
]    
});


It was not working If I do like this..